# Footer collapses php dynamic code

Tags: php, html, mysql

On clicking the [shop.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxeoT.jpg)

After [selecting product by category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/704MC.jpg)

I have problem with my footer. When I select the product by category, the footer comes up and covers the space that is allocated for the product selected on the basis of category. After 
[selecting category with no product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4nxb.jpg)

Can some one tell me what could be the problem with my code?. Here is my shop.php code

```
<?php
include('includes/db.php');
?>
<?php include('functions/functions.php'); ?>

<?php
include_once 'header.php';

?>
<?php
include_once 'topheader.php';

?>
<?php
include_once 'nav.php';

?>

<div id="content">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="breadcrumb">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php">Shop</a></li> 

</ul>  <!--breadcrumb ends--->  
</div> <!---col-md-12 ends-->

<div class="col-md-3">
<?php include("sidebar.php"); ?>  
</div> <!--col-md-3 ends--->

<div class="col-md-9">
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['p_cat'])){    
if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){

echo"
<div class='box'>
<h1>Welcome To Our Shop</h1>
<p>India's biggest online store for Paint,Dyes &amp; Tools and more! Largest selection from all Categories at lowest price.Payment options - COD,EMI,Credit card,Debit card &amp; more. Buy Now!</p>
</div>";
} 
}
?>

<div class="row">    
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['p_cat'])){     
if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){    
 $per_page=6;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page= $_GET['page'];    

}else{
    $page=1;

}
$start_from=($page-1) * $per_page;
$get_products="select * from products order by 1 DESC LIMIT $start_from,$per_page";
$run_products=mysqli_query($conn,$get_products);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)){
    $pro_id=$row['product_id'];
    $pro_title=$row['product_title'];
    $pro_price=$row['product_price'];
    $pro_img1=$row['product_img1'];

    echo "
    <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 center-responsive'>
<div class='product'>
 <div class='products'>
<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
<img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_img1'  class='img-responsive'>    
</a> 

<div class='text'>
<h3><a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>$pro_title</a></h3>
<p class='price'>&#x20b9; $pro_price </p>
<p class='buttons'>
<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' class='btn btn-default'>View Product</a>
<a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' class='btn btn-primary'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to Cart</a>
</p>
</div>    
</div>      

</div>     
</div>   ";
}

  ?>  

</div>  <!--row ends--->   

<center> 
<ul class="pagination">
<?php
$query="select * from products";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $total_records=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $total_pages= ceil($total_records / $per_page);
    echo"<li><a href='shop.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a></li>";
    for($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
        echo"<li><a href='shop.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
    };
    echo"<li><a href='shop.php=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></li>";
}
    }

    ?>
</ul> <!---ul ends-->   
</center> <!--center end-->
<?php 
    getPCatpro();

    ?>    
</div> <!---col-md-9 ends--->   -
</div> <!--container ends--> 
</div> <!---content ends-->





<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Is this an academic project, or one you're intending to deploy for actual (paying?) customers?

Comment: academic project. My working on the basic function and later on the security . Hence my php codes are not the latest. Will work later on the PDO later @tadman

Comment: @tadman i will send my codes to you if would like to take a look at them. Do let me know if i need any improvements!!

Comment: As this is a learning project I'd strongly encourage you to learn about placeholder values and `bind_param` with `mysqli`, that's the minimum you need to do for safe SQL. If you're looking for better examples of this, consider things like [Magento](https://magento.com) which are open-source and you can look at how they do it.

Comment: @tadman im running this on xaamp so no intention of implementing magneto. But  i will work on my bind_param with mysqli once the basic funtionality is done. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Magento is just a PHP software package that will run under XAAMP or any other PHP runtime environment. It's worth at least testing so you get a feel for what an ecommerce system needs to do.